# Linq To Sql Insert For This Statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Does this `insert sql statement` have a equivalent using `linq to sql` or how to write the insert in `linq to sql`?

```
INSERT INTO Table(FileId,  FileTitle, Action, FileAsBinary, UploadDate)

Values(NEWID(), 'Hello World Title', 'Upload',(  
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'C:\Files\Docs\TestDoc.docx',
   SINGLE_BLOB) AS x), GetDate())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you have to write a few lines of code to achive this. The Linq to Sql is just a light ORM for MSSQL.